# Querying Orion with metadata value of String type

Tags: metadata, fiware-orion

I am trying to query Orion, version 2.2.0-next, so to return records matching metadata value of different strings.

My JSON looks like this:

```
"AttributeName": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "Some Value",
        "metadata": {
            "AttributeMeta": {
                "type": "String",
                "value": "Some Other Value"
            }
        }
    }
```

I am querying Orion as follows:
http://myip:1026/v2/entities?type=myType&mq=AttributeName.AttributeMeta==Some%20Other%20Value&options=count

Unfortunately, the return is empty.

Any ideas, suggestions?

**EDIT**:

Entity creation code in PHP:

```
$data[] = array("id" => (mktime() + $i)."_$client", "type" => "myType", "datetime" => array("type" => "DateTime", "value" => date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", mktime($ho, $mi, $se, $mo, $da, $ye))), "Parameter1" => array("type" => "String", "value" => (string)$parameter1), "Parameter2" => array("type" => "Float", "value" => (float)$Parameter2), "Parameter3" => array("type" => "String", "value" => (string)$parameter3, "metadata" => array("Parameter3Meta" => array("type" => "String", "value" => "$parameter3meta"))), "location" => array("type" => "geo:point", "value" => "$lat, $lon"), "range" => array("type" => "Float", "value" => (float)$range), "Parameter4" => array("type" => "String", "value" => (string)$parameter4)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://$ip/v2/entities");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data[$i]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("fiware-service: $tenant", "fiware-servicepath: /$subtenant", "Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 1026);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

**EDIT 2**: In the above query two headers are used: fiware-service: tenant and fiware-servicepath: /subtenant

Answer (score 1):

Try removing 'type=myType'.
It's not clear what's the type of the entity you are trying to extract with the query.

Comment: By "myType" I mean the certain type I use in the schema. I did so (removed the type from the query), unfortunately the result is the same as previously.

Comment: In that case I can only assume the spaces in the value of the metadata is what's causing problems. It might help if you posted also the creation of the entity. Try a metadata value without whitespace. Meanwhile I will run a test with your exact data.

Comment: So, I implemented a quick test with mq string filter and a metadata with spaces in its value. Worked just fine ... Will need to see the curl command of the creation of your entity

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I have also tried without spaces, same result through Postman. I use PHP to create entities. Please, check my edited question for the entity creation code.

Comment: I see you use a tenant in the creation. I don't see any tenant in the query. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @AnastasiosOikonomidis, thanks for the edit including the details of the entity creation. Could you algo provide the same detail for the request that you use to query Orion, please?

Comment: @kzangeli I use both tenant and subtenant in the query as separate headers through Postman.

Comment: @fgalan I use both tenant and subtenant. All other queries are executed fine. I have edited my original question providing the headers. For testing I use Postman.

Comment: So, a mystery then ... :). If you could please do the same thing using two curl commands on command line, make sure you see the same error, and paste the commands here. I tried to copy your PHP code but was not able to see the error.